# Symfony 2 Exception: Class not found in Controller

Tags: class, exception, symfony

Okay so, I'm trying to create a new object of the class "Engineering_Detail" inside my custom action "next", the problem is, even though I'm using `"Use ....\Entity\Engineering_Detail"` it throws that error on the line i'm doing `$detail = new Engineering_Detail();`

> FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Mine\Bundle\EngMgmtBundle\Entity\Engineering_Detail' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\EngMgmt\src\Mine\Bundle\EngMgmtBundle\Controller\EngineeringController.php line 403

The line 403 is `$detail = new Engineering_Detail();`

Here's the important controller bits:

```
<?php

namespace Mine\Bundle\EngMgmtBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Mine\Bundle\EngMgmtBundle\Entity\Engineering;
use Mine\Bundle\EngMgmtBundle\Form\EngineeringType;
use Mine\Bundle\EngMgmtBundle\Entity\Engineering_Detail;
/**
 * Engineering controller.
 *
 * @Route("/engineering")
 */
class EngineeringController extends Controller
{
/**
     * Updates a Engineering entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/next/", name="engineering_next")
     * @Method("POST")
     * @Template("MineEngMgmtBundle:Engineering:update.html.twig")
     */
   public function nextAction(Request $request, $id){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('MineEngMgmtBundle:Engineering')->find($id);

        $current_form = $this->getForm($entity->getStatus()->getInternalOrder()); 
        $current_form->handleRequest($request);

        $detail = new Engineering_Detail();

        if ($current_form->isValid()) {

            $data = $current_form->getData();

            switch ($entity->getStatus()->getInternalOrder()){

                case 1:

                 if (($data["sitesurvey"]) == 'n'){
                     $status = $em->getRepository('MineEngMgmtBundle:Status')->findBy(array('internalOrder' => 8));
                     $next_form = $this->getForm($entity->getStatus()->getInternalOrder());
                }else{
                     $status = $em->getRepository('MineEngMgmtBundle:Status')->find(2);
                     $next_form = $this->getForm($entity->getStatus()->getInternalOrder());
                }    

                    break;

                default:
                     $status = $em->getRepository('MineEngMgmtBundle:Status')->findBy(array('internalOrder' => $entity->getStatus()->getInternalOrder()+1));
                     $next_form = $this->getForm($entity->getStatus()->getInternalOrder());
                    break;
            }

                     $detail->setEngineering($entity);
                     $detail->setFromStatus($entity->getStatus());
                     $detail->setToStatus($status);
                     $detail->setUpdatedDate(new \DateTime());
                     $detail->setUser($this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser());
                     $detail->setComments($data["comments"]);
                     $entity->setStatus($status);
                     $em->flush();
        }
            return array(
                        'entity' => $entity,
                        'form'   => $next_form->createView()
             );
    }
```

I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170948/symfony-2-class-not-found-in-controller) and verified but everything seems okay. That entity was generated using the tools inside the SF2 console. What am I doing wrong?

Note: I have already deleted cache

**EDIT:**

Tried with all other entities, using the same namespace and just changing the entity's name, and declaring objects, it seems the issue it's just with the entities with the **_** in their name.

Comment: are you sure that the namespace is correctly defined in the Engineering_Detail class?  Also, is your php file name the same as the Class name? (ex. Engineering_Detail.php)

Comment: It is the same name, and the namespace for Engineering_Detail class is namespace Mine\Bundle\EngMgmtBundle\Entity;

Comment: does your constructor for the Engineering_Detail class expect a parameter that may be missing? If it's the _ that may be causing the problem, can you try the same class without the _?

Comment: I haven't declared any constructor, I'm using the same entity generated with the SF console. Same as the others I tested, it should work same as it does with the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by deleting the _ in the entity name and changing all of its occurrences

Answer (score 4):

you are mixing PSR namespacing and class naming. The reason why it cannot be found is because your Entity should be called EngineeringDetail to be properly found by the autoloader.

Comment: I should give you the points, but I though you were really rude on the Issue list on github. You could've said it in a better way. Because how the hell would I know it's a bad practice?

Comment: sorry it came up wrong, did not mean to, you could have use the mailing list, that is all.