# can't "use" a form in symfony2.4

Tags: php, namespaces, symfony-2.4

this is probably a typo but I can't see it... it drives me crazy !

my structure is:

Bundle : /Symfony24/src/NRtworks/ChartOfAccountsBundle

My form: /Symfony24/src/NRtworks/ChartOfAccountsBundle/Form/Account_fastedit_form.php

The controller is like this:

```
<?php

namespace NRtworks\ChartOfAccountsBundle\Controller;
//form loading
use NRtworks\ChartOfAccountsBundle\Form\Account_fastedit_form;
use NRtworks\SubscriptionBundle\Form\NewCustomer;

class ChartOfAccountsController extends Controller
{
   public function indexAction()
   {
       new NewCustomer();
       new Account_fastedit_form();
   }

}

?>
```

my form class in Form/Account_fastedit_form.php

```
<?php

namespace NRtworks\ChartOfAccountsBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class Account_fastedit_form extends AbstractType
{
    //whatever
}
?>
```

then I get:

```
ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "Account_fastedit_form" from namespace "NRtworks\ChartOfAccountsBundle\Form" in /home/eagle1/www/Symfony24/src/NRtworks/ChartOfAccountsBundle/Controller/ChartOfAccountsController.php line 72. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?
```

I don't find my error.
ps: as you can see I can use my form NewCustomer, in another bundle without any problem, and the structure is similar...

Comment: Symfony might not like the fact you are mixing `CamelCase` and `snake_case` in your class naming scheme for `NRtworks\ChartOfAccountsBundle\Form\Account_fastedit_form`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this here and I can confirm that Symfony does not like the fact you have underscores in your class name.

Change the class to `AccountFasteditForm`, the file containing the class to `AccountFasteditForm.php` and update your `use` statements. It should work then.

**EDIT**

Hunting down some information about this, I suspected it was related to [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/). You'll find in the doc:

> Each _ character in the CLASS NAME is converted to a DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. The _ character has no special meaning in the namespace.

Implying that `_` is fine in namespaces but *not* in class names.

I also found reference in the Symfony docs that class names must be camel-case (again implying that underscored namespaces are fine)

[Here is a similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293411/symfony-2-exception-class-not-found-in-controller)